# jquery increment only works in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

```
$(".incrementer").click(function(){
    var values = $("#layernumber").val(); 
    var item = $("input[type=file]:last").clone(true);
    var txt = $(".layer_selector:last").after('<br>').clone(true);
    if($("#layernumber").val() < 4){
        $("#attach").append(item);
        $("#attach").append(txt);
    }  
    if($("#layernumber").val() > 2){
        $(".incrementer").hide();
    }
});
```

The above code increments the value of layers [image]

as the layers increments the file upload option will also.

But this works only in Chrome. Not in FireFox or Internet Explorer.

HTML code is:

```
<div class="tab-pane active" id="tab2">
    <h3 class="block">Provide your layer details</h3>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-3">Number of layer
            <span class="required" aria-required="true"> * </span>
        </label>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="input-group bootstrap-touchspin">
                <span class="input-group-addon bootstrap-touchspin-prefix" style="display: none;"></span>
                <input id="layernumber" type="text" class="form-control" name="layernumber" style="display: block;">
                <span class="input-group-addon bootstrap-touchspin-postfix" style="display: none;"></span>
                <span class="input-group-btn-vertical">
                    <button class="btn btn-default bootstrap-touchspin-up" type="button">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus incrementer"></i>
                    </button>
                    <button class="btn btn-default bootstrap-touchspin-down" type="button">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus decrementer"></i>
                    </button>
                </span>
            </div>
            <span class="help-block"> Provide your number of layers </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- fileupload starts-->        
    <!-- -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-3">Choose Layer
            <span class="required" aria-required="true"> * </span>
        </label>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <div id="attach">
            <div id="previewImg"></div>
                <div class="col-md-9">
                <input type="file" name="layerimages[]" onchange="preview(this);" class="myfile" id="fileid" multiple="">
                <select id="layerid" class="layer_selector" name="layer_selector">
                   <option value="">Please Select</option>    
                   <option value="0">First</option>
                   <option value="1">Second</option>
                   <option value="2">Intermediate</option>
                   <option value="3">Final</option>
                </select>
                </div> 
            </div>
            <br>   
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- fileupload ends-->
</div>
```

Comment: It really helps people if you take a little extra time to make sure that the code you post here is easily readable.

Comment: Please add the code where you call `Incrementer({ ... })` for initialising the `input` as incrementer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made a fiddle for this.

```
https://jsfiddle.net/w1gy8ruj/1/
```

The changes i did to your code is basically initialise the value of the layernumber input to 0 and increment it on every click.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".incrementer").click(function() {
    var values = $("#layernumber").val();
    var item = $("input[type=file]:last").clone(true);
    var txt = $(".layer_selector:last").after('<br>').clone(true);
    if ($("#layernumber").val() < 4) {
      $("#attach").append(item);
      $("#attach").append(txt);
    }
    if ($("#layernumber").val() > 2) {
      $(".incrementer-button").hide();
    }

    values++;
    $("#layernumber").val(values);
  });

});
```

Comment: Hi, I noticed it must be because you have the click handler on the i tag and it may not be getting clicked everytime as expected, i have changed it to click on the button element instead

Answer (score 0):

You do not use

```
var values = $("#layernumber").val();
```

anywhere in this scope, so this is unneeded unless you don't want to use it in the if statement below and for incrementing.

And you do not increment the layernumber, so

```
if($("#layernumber").val() > 2) {
```

will never execute. You should increment it and set it like

```
$("#layernumber").val(values)
```

Comment: @Rahul Ravindran answer fits your use case. one more thing: You should initialize the layernumber with 1 instead of 0, because your html already ships the first layer element.